# How to map a many-to-many relantionship in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm starting with OrientDB and I got the basics right. But I can't figured out how to map many-to-many relationships in a way that won't require me to make tons of integrity checking when removing a record.

I am using an object database (ODatabaseObjectTx) and I'm trying to map this simple relationship:

Person <-> Roles

A Person can have multiple Roles and a Role can be assigned to multiple Persons. N to M relationship.

My person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Role class:

```
public class Role {
    private String name;

    public Role() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now I can't figure out if I have to put a `Set<Role>` in the `User` class or a `Set<User>` in the `Role` class to make the links. Either way if I remove one record from one I have to check the links of the other to avoid `null` references. To me it is more convenient to place a `Set<Role>` in the `User` class.

In a RMDBS you can just create a foreign key and add some cascading rules, does OrientDB provide similar functionality to save me the bother of doing this manually?

If in the end I have to do this manually, what strategy should I take? Should I fully check the other cluster when removing a record? Should I just leave the `null`s and handle them when I see them? Should I create double references (having both `Set<Role>` in `User` AND `Set<User>` in `Role`, I guess this would bring faster removal at the cost of more space and complexity)?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at documentation: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Object-Database#cascade-deleting

Comment: I have tried that, it removes the whole record instead of just the reference. For example lets say I have that mapping in my `User` class at the `Set<Roles>` relationship, if I remove one `Role` then all users that have that `Role` will also be removed instead of just eliminating the reference in the `Set<Role>` of my `User`instances. It seems what I actually need is something like CascadeType.REFRESH.